# addAll() strangely updating HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, set

```
Map<String, HashSet<String>> mapp = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
set1.add("a");

HashSet<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();
set2.add("b");

mapp.put("A", set1);

set1.addAll(set2);

System.out.println(mapp.get("A"));
```

Output:

```
[b, a]
```

Shouldn't the output be just `[a]`? Is it something with `addAll()`? If `set1.addAll(set2)` is called after `mapp.put("A", set1)`, shouldn't `mapp` not include any part of `set2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `set1` is put into `mapp`, actually a reference is passed. This reference points to an object. The same reference is held by `set1`. So actually `set1` is the same object in memory as the result of `mapp.get("A")`. Which explains why `mapp.get("A")` holds the same values as `set1`. If you want the `Set` in `mapp.get("A")` to not interfer with the one held in `set1`, you'll have to create an entirely new object (a copy of `set1`).

Answer (score 1):

Since you put `set1` into your `Map` and modify it, this changes will be transient in the `Map`. It is the same object. the `add(...)` of `Map` does not copy the parameter. It inserts exactly this object into the `Map` and thus, changes made to the original entry (i.e. `set1`) are transiently seen in the `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

set1 is basically an object, the object is same, whatsoever you would add to set1 would be reflected in the map as well.

```
 set1.addAll(set2);
```

You are adding b to the set1 here, it is clearly visible in your code. Initially, it has just "a" and then you are adding b to it using setAll method which basically adds all the values of set2 to set1 ..

Hence, when you are looking at the values of set1, you are getting b and a.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove

```
set1.addAll(set2);
```

then it will print just a.

since

```
set1.addAll(set2);
```

adds the elements of set2 to set1, then the "A" key is updated to contain all new elements of set1. And when you call mapp.get("A") it returns the new contents of "A".